# issues with pandas dataframe insert to mysql with timestamp

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

Having issues with inserting pandas dataframe to MySQL db.Have listed the sample data and code used along with errors that follow.
How to insert data with pandas dataframe to mysql?

**Packages used**

```
Pandas - 0.22.0
sqlalchemy - 1.2.1
```

**Dataframe used:**

```
Out[135]: 
  P_ID  S_ID            Action                        Timestamp  \
0     Harold           1  Extensions 2017-11-07 03:17:27.342295+00:00   
1     Harold           1  Extensions 2017-11-07 03:17:27.447234+00:00   
2     Harold           1  Extensions 2017-11-07 03:17:27.552406+00:00   
3     Harold           1  Extensions 2017-11-07 03:17:27.657676+00:00   
4     Harold           1  Extensions 2017-11-07 03:17:27.762737+00:00   

       Value  
0 -0.096083  
1 -0.003894  
2 -0.004779  
3  0.131210  
4  0.161990
```

**dtypes :**

```
P_ID                 object
S_ID                 int64
Action               object
Timestamp            datetime64[ns, UTC]
Value                float64
dtype: object
```

The following code snippets were used with the errors followed

Also pd.to_datetime() did not seem to have any effect.

**Code used (1) without index**

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://xxxx:3306/xxxx')
test.to_sql(name='table1', con=engine, if_exists = 'append',index=False)
conn.close()
```

**Error :**

> ValueError: Cannot cast DatetimeIndex to dtype datetime64[us]

**Code used (2) with timestamp column indexed**

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://xxxx:3306/xxxx')
test.to_sql(name='table1', con=engine, if_exists = 'append',index=True,
                   index_label='Timestamp',
                   dtype={'Timestamp':typeTIMESTAMP(timezone=True)})
conn.close()
```

**Error :**

> ValueError: duplicate name in index/columns: cannot insert Timestamp, already exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow this API with MySQL does not seems to accept UTC timestamps.

The solutions that worked for me :

```
test['Timestamp']=test['Timestamp'].apply(lambda x:datetime.replace(x,tzinfo=None))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you convert the data type of `Timestamp` into `datetime64[us]` before writing to the DB it should work:

```
test['Timestamp'] = test['Timestamp'].values.astype('datetime64[us]')
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to convert Pandas timestamp to float and then to datetime but outside of DataFrame and right before inserting to database via:

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(value.timestamp())
```

It is very strange that MySQL cannot accept pandas timestamp by default...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html) to remove timezone

```
df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.tz_convert(None)
```

If pandas failed to detect datetimelike values, add [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

You can skip passing `format` & `dayfirst` if pandas is able to infer dates format in your data

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='mixed', dayfirst=False).dt.tz_convert(None)
```